# Question about metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have metric space $E$ and $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two different metrics on $E$ with the property that for all $x$ in $E$ and all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$,
such that $d_1(x,y)< \delta$ implies that $d_2(x,y) < \epsilon$. $U$ is a subset of $E$.

I want to prove that if $U$ is open with the distance $d_2$, then it is also open with the distance $d_1$.

This seems completely trivial to me, it makes a lot of sense. But I am having trouble constructing the proof.

What I have so far: A set $U$ that is a subset of $X$ is called open if, for each $x$ in $U$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that a ball of center $x$ and radius $\epsilon$ is a subset of $U$. We see that $U$ is open with distance $d_2$ so for each $p$ in $E$ such that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $\epsilon$.
 However, if the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $\epsilon$, then $x$ and $y$ must be less than $\delta$, as given by the problem. Is this really this simple.

Comment: I think your first paragraph is missing something.

Comment: ^ Sorry the "<" cut it off, edited it!

Comment: This question was edited (an edit which was approved) in a way that seemed to conflict with OP's intent, even though an answer was already posted. Additionally, a lot of incoherences in the notation were introduced. I rolled back to the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U \subset E$ be an open set with respect to $d_{2}$.

Fix $x \in U$, since $U$ is open there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that

$$ y \in E , d_{2}(x,y)<\varepsilon \rightarrow y\in U$$

By hypothesis, for this $\varepsilon$ there exists somr $\delta >0$ such that:

$$d_{1}(x,y)<\delta \rightarrow d_{2}(x,y)<\varepsilon$$

Hence taking $y \in E$ such that $d_{1}(x,y)<\delta$ we see that $y \in U$. Hence $x$ is an interior point of $U$ with respect to $d_{1}$. Since $x \in U$ was arbitrary, this means that $U$ is open with the distance $d_{1}$.

Comment: does the arrow you show mean "then"

Comment: Yes, the arrow was supposed to mean "then", or "this implies". I has originally typed "then" but couldn't get the spacing right with LaTeX.

Comment: great! Makes perfect sense. So would there ever be an example where U is open with d1 but not with d2? Just wondering

Comment: Hmmm consider $E=\mathbb{R},d_{2}(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_{1}$ the discrete metric. Then taking $\delta = 1/2$ will work for any $\varepsilon >0$. Now note that {0} is open with $d_{1}$ (again taking $\delta =1/2$ but it is not with $d_{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help! I really appreciate it. I am still a little confused with why {0} is open in d1 and not d2

Comment: How is d2 open?

Comment: Recall that the discreet metric is $d_{1}(x,y)=0$ when $x=y$, and $d_{1}(x,y)=1$ otherwise. Hence if we take the set of all $y\in mathbb{R}$ such that $d_{1}(0,y)<1/2$, this set just {0}, and hence it is a subset of {0}. Therefore {0} is open. {0} is not open with respect to $d_{2}$ because any interval $(-\eta ,\eta),\eta >0$ (that is a neighbourhood of $0$ with respect to d_{2}) is not contained in {0}.

Comment: So that says y in R  and any interval (-n,n)  , n > 0
if so makes perfect sense!!!! Thanks